# Getting an out_of_range: vector error for c++ but can't figure out why

Tags: c++, vector

This is my code:

```
StockAccount::StockAccount() {
    vector<string> temp;
    string line;
    std::ifstream stockfile("Results.txt");
    if (stockfile.is_open()) {
        while (stockfile.good()) {


            getline(stockfile, line);
            istringstream ss(line);
            string token;
            while (std::getline(ss, token, ',')) {
                temp.push_back(token);
            }

            addStock(temp.at(0), temp.at(1), temp.at(2));

        temp.clear();

        }
        stockfile.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

}
```

I know it isn't THAT efficient, that is what I am trying to fix. What it is supposed to be doing is:

1. Read that file line by line.
2. Parse each line and split it by comma.
3. Take those 3 values and use it in a method.

I am using that vector temp to store the values, add them to the function and then clear it so that it can be empty and used again to store the next ones ...etc.

I tried printing out each value BEFORE the temp.clear() and they all print out and THEN I get the error. So I know that temp.clear() is the problem. Perhaps I am using the wrong method, or there is a much better way.

I want to try and NOT use boost if possible.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector
```

Results.txt is a file that looks like.

goog,525,0
msft,34,10

and so on.

Comment: You are accessing up to index `2` without checking the size of the vector. An out of range error is not so surprising.

Comment: I know that each line will have 3 elements though.

Comment: OK, then it must be a compiler bug. Only joking.

Comment: Ha. I'm using clang++ with C++11 on Mavericks.

Comment: You'll have better replies if you post the contents of Results.txt with code that will let us replicate the error.

Comment: Put in a quick idea of what it looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`while (stockfile.good())` is wrong, and leads to your reading one extra, non-existent line.

That's because you're checking for stream validity *before* attempting to read a new line; if there's no new line to read, it's only *after* the call to `getline` that this condition would evaluate to `false` but by then it's too late and you're off trying to handle this non-existent line.

That non-existent line does not have three tokens on it, but you are performing no error checking on the tokenization, nor are you ever verifying the size of the vector `temp`.

So, when you come to try to access those three vector elements, which don't exist, an exception is thrown.

Your loop should look like this:

```
while (getline(stockfile, line)) {
    istringstream ss(line);
    string token;
    // ...
}
```

Notice how I directly check for success *in* the loop condition, which will prevent the loop body from being executed if the actual `getline` fails.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks. I'm also putting in a size check to make sure(even though it'll never be that way). I see what you did with your solution. One less step and handles what I was trying to do in a better(and working) way.